# Regex - trying to match / \ | , or newline, error says invalid escape character

Tags: java, regex, escaping, string-matching

I'm actually trying to split a string on any of the following :

- /
- \
- |
- ,
- \n

Here's the regex I'm using, which gives the 'invalid escape character' error :

```
String delims = "[\\\\\|\\/\\n,]+"; 
String[] list1 = str1.split(delims);
```

I've tried a few more versions of this, trying to get the number of \'s right. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Look into String literals and valid escape sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"[/\\|\n,\\\\]+"
```

Some of these you need to double escape

```
/ matches /
\\| matches |
\n matches new line
, matches ,
\\\\ matches \
```

Comment: `|` doesn't need to be escaped inside `[...]`, it is acceptable but it can confuse people and make them wonder if they have to use it in this context or not.

Answer (score 1):

To create `\` literal in regex engine you need to write it with four `\` in string, so you have one `\` extra

```
"[\\\\\|\\/\\n,]+"; 
  1234^ 
      here
```

Also you don't need to escape `/` in Java regex engine, and you don't need to pass `\n` as `\\n` (`\n` literal will be also accepted) you can so try with

```
String delims = "[\\\\|/\n,]+";
```